# Can we formulate a probability density distribution (not function!) for every probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know that **not** every probability measure admits a probability density function, where a function is a mapping $f: X \to \mathbb R$.

However, there is something, such as the Dirac delta distribution, which is **not** a function, because it is defined as that whose integral is the step function. There is, of course, no mapping $f:X\to \mathbb R$ that has as its integral the step function, so the Dirac delta distribution is not a function. (It is a "generalized function").

Is it possible for every conceivable (probability) measure on every conceivable space, to define for it a (probability)-measure **density** **distribution** (i.e. NOT necessarily a function), using tools similar to the Dirac delta distribution?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "density distribution"?

Comment: For a real valued random variable $X$, then $F(x) = P(X <x)$ is an increasing bounded function, thus its distributional derivative $f = F'$ is a non-negative distribution of order $0$ (a finite measure) and $F = f \ast 1_{x > 0}$ in $L^1_{loc}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael, by density distribution I mean whatever other people mean who have come up with something like the diract delta function for the step cumulative distribution, if they have.

Comment: In other words, a probability measure?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, You must know that there is a difference between the dirac delta function and the step function? How can you then possibly assume that I'm looking for the probability measure? The dirac delta function is the probability density "function" in the case that the cumulative probability distribution is the step function. I'm asking if there is a generalization of this idea to all possible probability spaces, so that even probability measures that don't admit a density function, have some kind of "generalized density distribution", similar to the dirac delta function.

Comment: I don't know exactly what that would look like, but it seems pretty clear from the question that I'm not looking for a probability measure, since this is more of a generalization of the cumulative distribution, rather than the density distribution.

Comment: The Dirac delta "function" can be considered as a probability measure, namely the unit mass at $0$, or as a distribution, i.e. a functional on a space of test functions, in this case giving the value at $0$.

Comment: You can mix the two possibilities - density function for the intervals where the cdf is continuous and weighted dirac delta functions (weight = size of jump) at the discontinuities.